# Wordpress - check if current browser is logged in to a Wordpress site from an external server

Tags: php, wordpress, icecast

TLDR: Can I have a script on a server to check if the current web-browser is logged in to a particular Wordpress site?

Long version:
I am attempting to set up an audio player on a Wordpress website which streams from an Icecast server. The Icecast server is set up for "http" authentication, in that when it receives a request for a file, it sends a request to an external server to make the yes/no decision - with an "ok" header being sent back to the server if everything is ok, which then allows the original request from the Wordpress website.

To the end-user this is all happening on a Wordpress site secured by a user/pass, so what I really want to happen is the Wordpress site requests the file from the Icecast server, the server then sends a request back to a custom.php on the Wordpress site which then checks if the user's browser has a current logged in session in my Wordpress site. If so, then send the "ok" header back to complete the loop.

Ive got the header working, but not the bit that checks for a logged in Wordpress session. I believe this is because its "session" is originating from the (separate) server and not on the client's browser.

I'm tying myself up in knots with this!

Icecast mount point XML:

```
<mount-name>/stream99.aac</mount-name>
    <authentication type="url">
        <option name="listener_add" value="https://myserver.com/listener_joined.php"/>
        <option name="username" value="user"/>
        <option name="password" value="pass"/>
        <option name="auth_header" value="icecast-auth-user: 1"/>
        <option name="timelimit_header" value="icecast-auth-timelimit:"/>
        <option name="headers" value="x-pragma,x-token"/>
        <option name="header_prefix" value="ClientHeader."/>
    </authentication>
</mount>
```

Working "listener_joined.php":

```
<?php
        header('icecast-auth-user: 1');
?>
```

I've attempted lots of combinations of Wordpress' is_user_logged_in() found on here, but with none working. I believe this is because it is the **Icecast server** that is polling for info (ie not logged in).

Hopefully someone can help - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a querystring parameter instead.

```
https://icecast.example.com/stream?sessionid=abcdef1234567890
```

This way, you don't have to worry about headers, nor cross-origin cookies.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, not sure I follow though. Do you mean use a querystring to pass a user/pass to the server instead of doing the Icecast http auth? In which case this is what I was trying to avoid because of security concerns that I’d read about. Otherwise, do you mean passing something to Wordpress somehow in the querystring?

Comment: Use the querystring to pass some sort of session ID, not a username/password.  What security concerns do you have?  It's the only way to do it.  You can't use basic auth in the URI anymore... it no longer works.

Comment: I've been attempting just this today with limited success.... The player that I'm using seems to poll the server in a few different ways to get metadata, some of which don't pass any querystrings. I think I'm going to need to re-make it with some JSON work. Re: security - I need the streams to be private, both with obscurity and authentication. All points are HTTPS so I guess the querystring is my only option.

Comment: A lot of stations use a querystring, or some other identifier in the URL, to authorize the stream.  Note that if you wanted, you could crytographically "sign" URLs so that they can only be used for a limited time.  The downside though is that players tend to reconnect over time.  I've found that the best way to do this is a simple query string.  And yes, you should be using HTTPS all the time.